# Better understanding Ext.tab.Panel and explicitly setting the html

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, openseadragon

I want to use a third party image library that needs to be instantiated with a string value that was used for a corresponding div id. 
With that, I would like to use `Ext.tab.Panel` to be able to switch between each instantiated instance of the third party image library. 
I’m struggling with being able to set the div's id on the containers of each tab.

**For example:**

```
Ext.define('MYAPP.view.MainView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'mainview',
    controller: 'mainviewcontroller',
    layout: 'fit',

    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'somebuttons',
    }],

    items: [{
        xtype: 'imagetab',
        title: 'tab1',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            html: '<div id="instance1"></div>'
        }]
    }, {
        xtype: 'imagetab',
        title: 'tab2',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            html: '<div id="instance2"></div>'
        }]
    }]
});
```

Then in the `MainView` controller, I listen to `onBoxReady` event and instantiate each instance of the third-party image library with the names `instance1` and `instance2` (same as the tab containers div id’s).

The third-party image library is instantiated fine, but the images don't show. When I inspect each tab's corresponding containers, there div ids aren’t what I set them to be above.

i.e.:

```
html: '<div id="instance1"></div>' or id="instance2"></div>'
```

Does anyone have any thoughts in how to set the div's id of each tab's containers?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `imagetab`? You can see here it's not modifying the content you provide: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ira

Comment: I assume the library is OpenSeadragon? I don't know anything about Ext.js, but I can tell you that you can instantiate OpenSeadragon with an element instead of an ID, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        id: 'instance1',
        autoEl: {
            id: 'instance1', // must be same as container id 
            ......
        }
    }]
});
```

It will create div with an id.

Comment: @Linker256 if it is as per expectation could you please approve this answer for future reference.